# How to convert an empty array and empty object to an empty string or null

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, string

How can I convert an **empty array** to an **empty string** or `null`?

```
$empty_array = array();

var_dump($empty_array);
```

result,

```
array(0) { }
```

Also for an empty object below,

```
class null_object{};
$null_object = new null_object();
var_dump($null_object);
```

result,

```
object(null_object)#4 (0) { }
```

I am after `null` or just something like `$empty_array = '';` whenever they are found empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
function convert($array) {
    return (count($array) === 0) ? "" : $array;
}

$empty_array = array();
$empty_array = convert($empty_array);
```

This will simply convert it into a empty string if the array is empty.

An object is somewhat more complicated but you can just use [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/get_object_vars):

```
function convert($object) {
    return (count(get_object_vars($object)) === 0) ? "" : $object;
}
```

Nb.: You cannot check an object on private variables.

Comment: thanks for the answer. what about an empty object? sorry please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Using `implode()` for the simpler solution.

```
echo implode('',(array)$array_or_object);
```