# Json encode from XML file creates empty array if element in XML is empty

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

I have a XML file, where some elements will be empty. The issue is, that this code, creates an empty array, if the element is empty. Som for the XML example below, the result from JSON_DECODE would be:

I have tried setting depth to two, with no luck.

```
[26272] => Array (
    [productname] => Some product name
    [ean] => Array ( )
)
```

Example XML:

```
<item>
    <productname>Some product name</productname>
    <ean></ean>
</item>
```

The code i´m using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$json = json_encode($xml,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$products = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: This is a fundamental limitation of the XML format. It can't distinguish between empty lists and empty strings. Simple XML assumes that `<ean></an>` is an empty list.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Ofcourse I can check if every element is an array, and work from there, but the real life XML has a lot more elements. Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: I looked at all the flags available to `simplexml_load_file()`, I don't see any that will make it load `<ean></ean>` as a string node rather than an element.

Comment: Can you just [remove empty nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603358/231316) from the XML?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Haven´t thought about Xpath, that could actually be a solution. I will look in to it.

Barmar Thanks for the try - I hope to find a good solution.

Comment: There is no unique correct way of converting JSON to XML that will please everyone. Every conversion library does it differently. The only way of getting the precise XML you want is either (a) do the conversion yourself, or (b) post-process the result using XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for your comment. But the issue is the other way around - The source file is XML, i converts it to JSON, which is converted to an array.

Comment: Sorry yes, but the same considerations apply: the converter is unlikely to give you exactly the JSON you want. Again, you either need to write the conversion yourself (I would do it in XSLT 3), or post-process the output in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, if someone else can use it. I figured it out, by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15845602/18418004), and used this function, to run through and replace the empty arrays:

```
function replaceArrayToString($arr) {
   $newArr = array();
   foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
   {
       if (is_array($value))
       {
          unset($arr[$key]);

           //Is it an empty array, make it a string
           if (empty($value)) {
               $newArr[$key] = '';
           }
           else {
               $newArr[$key] = replaceArrayToString($value);
           }

       }
       else {
           $newArr[$key] = $value; 
       }

   }
   return $newArr;

}
```